# Avoiding LNK2005 errors in Visual studio

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have these files:

[main.c](http://pastebin.com/9KxQRr68)

[myLib.h](http://pastebin.com/NTbimJXu)

[myLib.c](http://pastebin.com/gqcZSHgs)

but when I'm trying to compile the whole project this error returned:

```
1>myLib.obj : error LNK2005: _start_server already defined in main.obj
1>C:\Users\n3tpum63r\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\NewMultiPlex2\Debug\main.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I searched it in Google and found this

```
"LNK2005 Errors When Link C Run-Time Libraries Are Linked Before MFC Libraries"
```

but couldn't fix it.

How can this error be fixed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of line #1 of myLib.h - you should never normally be #including a .c file.

Conversely in myLib.c you should probably *add* `#include "myLib.h"` at the top of the file - it's not strictly necessary at this point in your project but it's a good habit to get into for when you start "real world" programming.

It also looks like you're missing a bunch of system #includes in myLib.c.

The rest looks more or less OK and it should compile and link with the above change(s).

Comment: I remove the #include myLib.c from myLib.h and add the #include "myLib.h" at the top of the myLib.c and all worked. Thank you.